# Is there a way to vectorize logical comparison like greater than in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

[image]

I've a function like this which returns result after comparing certain columns against the function arguments. For instance P =[0.2,5,5] and it gets compared against the relevant columns. I've to do this against a range of values and possibly would have to run some optimization algorithm as well. Right now I'm using loops to change values of P. But I was wondering if there's a way to vectorize this process. So `p[0]`,`P[1]` and `P[2]` can be given as vectors and the output is a vector for all the combinations?

```
TP =(np.sum(dsf[(dsf.SCORE>P[0]) & (dsf.CANDIDATE_FRAMES>P[1])]
       .groupby(['ELD_ID'])
       .size().reset_index(name='event_count')
       .query('event_count > @P[2]').ELD_ID.isin(annotator.ELD_ID)))
```

Comment: Please ask your question properly. That implies adding your code directly in the question - not as an image - as well as having good examples to underline your problem.

Comment: Your code is not reproducible, so you cannot hope to get help right now

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. The actual part I want help on is the one I've included in the question. 'TP=..'

Comment: then use code formatting (with ` symbols) and imports for a valid code

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out. Will make the changes!

Comment: that is an improvment... but still not good enough. what is 'dsf'? what is 'annotator'? where are the imports? the goal is to make a code that can be copy-pasted and reproduce the error/feature you detected